# Minesweeper project

Tags: java, minesweeper

I wrote out a Minesweeper clone for a compsci project. I'm concerned a lot about code efficiency - any suggestions on how I could streamline my code to make it more efficient?

This is the [repo](https://github.com/asi14/minesweeper) for it, if you want to compile/run the program.

**MineHandler.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Component;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class MineHandler extends JFrame{
  protected Minesweeper obj; //has the "board"
  private JPanel god; //minesweeper layout design
  private JPanel menu; //menu layout design (preceding god)
  private JPanel top, bottom; //top and bottom stuff on the board

  private ImageIcon cover;

  private JButton easy, medium, hard, custom; //button layout
  private JButton menuReturn;
  private JLabel text, image, difficulty;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    MineHandler crystal = new MineHandler();
  }
  public MineHandler(){

    obj = new Minesweeper();
    menuOpener();
  }

  //you'll need to clean up the UI in a bit
  public void menuOpener(){ //brings up the main menu
    setTitle("Minesweeper");
    setSize(300,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    menu = new JPanel();
    menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menu, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


    text = new JLabel();
    text.setText("Minesweeper");
    text.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    cover = new ImageIcon("../img/icon.png");
    image = new JLabel(cover);
    image.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    easy = new JButton();
    easy.setText("Easy");
    easy.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        obj.easy();
        obj.buildInit();
        difficulty = new JLabel();
        difficulty.setText("EASY Mode: Minesweeper");
        buildGui();
      }
    });
    easy.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    medium = new JButton();
    medium.setText("Medium");
    medium.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        obj.medium();
        obj.buildInit();
        setSize(400,400);
        difficulty = new JLabel();
        difficulty.setText("MEDIUM Mode: Minesweeper");
        buildGui();
      }
    });
    medium.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    hard = new JButton();
    hard.setText("Hard");
    hard.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        obj.hard();
        obj.buildInit();
        setSize(1000,1000);
        difficulty = new JLabel();
        difficulty.setText("HARD Mode: Minesweeper");
        buildGui();
      }
    });
    hard.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    custom = new JButton();
    custom.setText("Custom");
    custom.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("custom");
      }
    });
    custom.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    menu.add(text);
    menu.add(image);
    menu.add(easy);
    menu.add(medium);
    menu.add(hard);
    menu.add(custom);

    add(menu);

    setVisible(true);
  }
  public void buildGui(){
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().repaint();

    System.out.println("Build Gui intiated");


    god = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    //board = obj.buildBoard();

    top = new JPanel();

    top.add(difficulty);

    bottom = new JPanel();
    menuReturn = new JButton();
    menuReturn.setText("Return to Menu");
    menuReturn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().repaint();

        menuOpener();
        validate();
      }
    }); //add mouse listener



    bottom.add(menuReturn);


    god.add(obj.board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    god.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    god.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(god);
    validate();
  }

}

//begin to implement flag operations
```

**Minesweeper.java**

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
public class Minesweeper{
  /*
  0: empty space:
  1 ~ 8 : bomb next to it
  9: key bomb (same bomb for successfully uncovered bombs in fail and pass)
  10: flag
  11: unused
  12: incorrect flags
  13: the bomb user clicked in loss
  14: covered space
  */
  private int length, width; //sets the length and width
  private Cell[][] array;
  protected int[][] key;
  protected int[][] userArray;
  private int[][] chainReactionSet;
  private int bombs;
  private Random box;
  protected JPanel board;
  //add mouse event here?
  public Minesweeper(){

    box = new Random();
  }

  public void easy(){
    length = 10;
    width = 10;
    bombs = 10;
  }

  public void medium(){
    length = 16;
    width = 16;
    bombs = 40;
  }

  public void hard(){
    length = 30;
    width = 35;
    bombs = 99;
  }
  public void buildInit(){
    bombInit();
    buildBoard();
    chainReactionSet = new int[key.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
      chainReactionSet[i] = key[i].clone();
    }
  }
  public void bombInit(){
    key = new int[length][width];
    for(int i = 0; i< bombs; i++){
      key[box.nextInt(length)][box.nextInt(width)] = 9;
    }
    toString(key);
    numberSet();
    genUserArray();
  }
  //needs fixing
  public void winValidate(){
    //conditions: ALL flags must be CORRECTLY paired with ALL the bombs AND all blank spaces must be cleared out
    boolean isWin = true;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < userArray.length; i ++){
      for(int a = 0 ; a < userArray[0].length; a++){
        if(array[i][a].isMine == true && array[i][a].isFlagged == false){ //checks to see all bombs are paired with correct flags
          isWin = false;

        }

        else if(array[i][a].isFlagged == false && array[i][a].isEnabled == true){
          isWin = false;

        }
      }
    }
    if(isWin == true){
      win();
    }

  }
  public void win(){
    for(int i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
      for(int a = 0; a < key[0].length; a++){
        array[i][a].isEnabled = false;
      }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You won");
  }



  private void numberSet(){

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
      for (int a = 0; a < key[0].length; a++){
        //If it Is not a mine
        if (key[i][a] == 0){
          int count = 0;
          //Position of cells around key[i][a] relative to key[i][a]
          for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++){
            for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++){
              //Storing x and y test points
              int testX = i + x;//testX = i-1, i, and i+1
              int testY = a + y;//testY = i-1, y, and y+1
              //If the testX and testY values are within the range of the array
              if ((testX >= 0 && testX < length) && (testY >= 0 && testY < width)){
                //If there is a mine
                if (key[testX][testY] == 9){count++;}

              }
            }
          }
          key[i][a] = count;


        }

      }
    }
  }

  private void genUserArray(){
    userArray = new int[length][width];
    for(int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++){
      for(int a = 0; a < userArray[0].length; a++){
        userArray[i][a] = 14;
      }
    }
  }

  private JPanel buildBoard(){

    board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(length,width));
    array = new Cell[length][width];
    for(int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++){ //set all the arrays in the cell array to 14
      for(int a =0 ; a < userArray[0].length; a++){
        array[i][a] = new Cell(i,a,this);
        array[i][a].changeIcon(userArray[i][a]);
        if(key[i][a] == 9){array[i][a].isMine = true;}
        //System.out.println("here");
        board.add(array[i][a].button);
      }
    }
    return board;
  }

  public void chainReaction(int col, int row){
    chainReactionSet[col][row] = -2;
    if(key[col][row] != 0){
      array[col][row].updateNum(key[col][row]);
      array[col][row].isEnabled = false;
      array[col][row].isNumbered = true;
    }
    else if(key[col][row] == 0){
      array[col][row].changeIcon(key[col][row]);
      array[col][row].isEnabled = false;
      array[col][row].isBlank = true;
      for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++){
        for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++){
          //Storing x and y test points
          int testX = col + x;//testX = i-1, i, and i+1
          int testY = row + y;//testY = i-1, y, and y+1
          //If the testX and testY values are within the range of the array
          if ((testX >= 0 && testX < length) && (testY >= 0 && testY < width)){
            //If there is a mine
            if (key[testX][testY] != 9 && chainReactionSet[testX][testY] != -2){


              chainReaction(testX,testY);

            }

          }
        }

      }
    }


  }
  public static void toString(int[][] arr){
    for(int a[] : arr){
      for(int b : a){
        System.out.print(b + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  public void fail(){
    for(int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++){
      for(int a = 0; a < userArray[0].length; a++){
        array[i][a].isEnabled = false;
        if(userArray[i][a] == 13){
          continue;
        }
        if(userArray[i][a] == 10 && key[i][a] != 9){
          array[i][a].changeIcon(12);
        }
        else if(userArray[i][a] == 10 && key[i][a] == 9){
          continue;
        }
        else if(key[i][a] == 0 || key[i][a] == 9){
          array[i][a].changeIcon(key[i][a]);
        }
        else{
          array[i][a].updateNum(key[i][a]);
        }
      }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost");
  }
}
```

**Cell.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.Insets;
public class Cell{
  private ImageIcon image;
  protected int status, col,row; //status records the current STATUS OF THE CELL
  protected JButton button;
  private Minesweeper miney;
  protected boolean isEnabled;
  protected boolean isMine;
  protected boolean isFlagged;
  protected boolean isNumbered;
  protected boolean isBlank;
  //protected Mouse mouseBox;
  public Cell(int i,int a, Minesweeper miney){
    isEnabled = true;
    isFlagged = false;
    isBlank = false;
    col = i;
    row = a;
    this.miney = miney;
    //mouseBox = new Mouse(i,a);
    button = new JButton();
    //button.addMouseListener(mouseBox);
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
          if(isEnabled){
            if(miney.userArray[col][row] == 10){}
            else if(miney.key[col][row] == 9){
              miney.userArray[col][row] = 13;
              changeIcon(13);
              miney.fail();
            }
            else if(miney.key[col][row] == 0){
              miney.chainReaction(col,row);

            }

            else{
              if(isEnabled){
                miney.userArray[col][row] = miney.key[col][row];
                updateNum(miney.key[i][a]);
                isEnabled = false;
                isNumbered = true;
              }

            }
            miney.winValidate();
          }

        }
        else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
          if(isEnabled){
            if(miney.userArray[col][row] == 10){
              miney.userArray[col][row] = 14;
              status = 14;
              changeIcon(14);
              isFlagged = false;
            }
            else if(miney.userArray[col][row] == 14){
              miney.userArray[col][row] = 10;
              status = 10;
              changeIcon(10);
              isFlagged = true;
            }
            miney.winValidate();
          }

        }

      }
    });

  }
  public void updateNum(int num){
    status = num;
    button.setIcon(null);
    String text = Integer.toString(num);
    System.out.println(num);
    button.setText(text);

    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    button.setEnabled(false);
  }
  public void changeIcon(int img){ //adds the image to the button
    status = img;
    String directory = "../img/" + status + "box.png";
    ImageIcon box = new ImageIcon(directory);


    button.setIcon(box);

  }
  public JButton addCell(){//adds the cell to the larger array
    return button;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote out a Minesweeper clone for a compsci project. I'm concerned a lot about code efficiency

What is *your* definition of "code efficiency"?
I assume it is performance.

In that case there is a name for this: *premarture optimization*.

Java is especially designed to save the programmer from low level performacne considerations most of the time. Therefore your major concern should be  *redability* and *maintainability* of your code (unless you have *proven* a performence problem with your code).

> any suggestions on how I could streamline my code to make it more efficient?

- Know and use the 4 rules of [simple design](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BeckDesignRules.html).
- Know and follow the [S.O.L.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle

---

When looking at your code example I'd suggest the following:

#### readability

Your code uses *magic numbers* wich you describe in a comment.

Instead of that comment declare public constants which provides neaningfull names:

```
 public static final int EMPTY = 0;
 public static final int FLAG = 10;
```

Or even better an `enum` in its own class) The probem here is that you "reuse" the same variable for different semantics: values 1 to 8 are "the neigbours state" all other values are "the cells own state". If we put this aside the `enum` would be like this

```
public enum CellState{
  EMPTY_COVERED, BOMB_COVERED, EMPTY_UNCOVERED, BOMB_UNCOVERED
}
```

### separation of concerns

Your class `Cell` looks pretty much like a *model class* providing data handling. But this should not know about GUI classes like `JButton` or controller classes like `ActionListener`

This is how **I** would do this part (only display, no covering/uncovering):

Cell.java

```
class Cell {
    Collection<Cell> neigbours = new HashSet<>();
    private final boolean isBomb;

    public Cell(boolean isBomb) {
        this.isBomb = isBomb;
    }

    public void addNeigbour(Cell other) {
        neigbours.add(other);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (isBomb)
            return "X";

        int neigbourBombCount = countBombs(neigbours);
        if (0 == neigbourBombCount)
            return " ";
        return String.valueOf(neigbourBombCount);
    }

    private int countBombs(Collection<Cell> neigbours2) {
        int neigbourBombCount = 0;
        for (Cell cell : neigbours2) {
            if (cell.isBomb)
                neigbourBombCount++;
        }
        return neigbourBombCount;
    }
}
```

MineSweeper.java

```
public class MineSweeper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell[][] gameField = configureFields();
        JTable jTable = prepareDisplay(gameField);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable);
    }

    private static Cell[][] configureFields() {
        Cell[][] gameField = initializeCellArray();
        setCellNeigbours(gameField);
        return gameField;
    }

    private static void setCellNeigbours(Cell[][] gameField) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameField.length; i++) {
            Cell[] fieldRow = gameField[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldRow.length; j++) {
                Cell currentCell = fieldRow[j];
                setCellNeigbours(gameField, i, fieldRow, j, currentCell);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Cell[][] initializeCellArray() {
        final int bombLikelyness = 7;
        Cell[][] gameField = new Cell[50][30];
        for (int i = 0; i < gameField.length; i++) {
            Cell[] fieldRow = gameField[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldRow.length; j++) {
                gameField[i][j] = new Cell(0 == new Random().nextInt(bombLikelyness) % bombLikelyness);
            }
        }
        return gameField;
    }

    private static void setCellNeigbours(Cell[][] gameField, int i, Cell[] fieldRow, int j, Cell currentCell) {
        if (0 < i && 0 < j)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i - 1][j - 1]);
        if (0 < j)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i][j - 1]);
        if (0 < i)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i - 1][j]);
        if (gameField.length > i + 1 && fieldRow.length > j + 1)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i + 1][j + 1]);
        if (gameField.length > i + 1)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i + 1][j]);
        if (fieldRow.length > j + 1)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i][j + 1]);

        if (0 < i && fieldRow.length > j + 1)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i - 1][j + 1]);
        if (gameField.length > i + 1 && 0 < j)
            currentCell.addNeigbour(gameField[i + 1][j - 1]);
    }


    private static JTable prepareDisplay(Cell[][] gameField) {
        DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return gameField.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return gameField[0].length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return gameField[column][row];
            }
        };

        JTable jTable = new JTable(defaultTableModel);
        jTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15*gameField.length, 20*gameField[0].length));

        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int column) {
                 JLabel rendererComponent = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                 rendererComponent.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
                 switch (value.toString()) {
                case "X":
                     rendererComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case " ":
                     rendererComponent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    break;

                default:
                     rendererComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
                }
                return rendererComponent;
            }
        });
        return jTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: If Cell.java doesn't handle user input (e.g. if a cell gets clicked), does that mean that role would go to Minesweeper.java? Any suggestions as to manage user input from Minesweeper.java's view for each of the cells?

Comment: @BrianLee *"If Cell.java doesn't handle user input (e.g. if a cell gets clicked), does that mean that role would go to Minesweeper.java?"* In your implementation the handling of user input should go the `MineHandler` since this is the *user interface* in your implementation. `MineHandler` should display the content of the `Cell`s and translate user input into call to class `Minesweeper` to change the values in `Cell`. Your class `Minesweeper` is the *controller* working with the Model (`Cell`).